# A bunch of relatively small images are reading at 1 MB/s via Samba

Tags: networking, samba

I have a bunch of images of total size of 6Gb, but each of which is relatively small. I am trying to copy these images over LAN and the speed of copying is approximately 1 MB/s.

It is slower than Internet nowadays.

My LAN has gigabit speed. Looks like this is happens only with lots of small files. When I am copying one large file, speed is more than 100 MB/s.

Is it possible to make samba faster for a bunch of small files?

Answer (score 2):

You can't make Samba faster for small files, because Samba is not the issue.

The best way to transfer a large amount of small files is to compress them into an archive first, and then transfer the entire archive.  You may even find the entire process of compress>transfer>extract to be faster than transferring all the files.

The reason is two parts, overhead, and hard drive operations.  There's more overhead on the network when transferring multiple files compared to a single file since each file has many attributes that go along with it.  And, your hard drive works harder to allocate space to write each packet from its buffer.  If you have a mechanical drive, then you also have to factor in seek time added to it, and the hard drive's operation of fitting the data into sectors.  SSD's aren't affected as much.

You'll find the same problem when transferring files from HDD to HDD, or from USB drive to HDD.  It's the overhead of many individual files.

Comment: OS could prefetch directory information, why not?

Comment: The OS could get the entire directory structure, but each file is still transferred one at a time.  It's the network overhead that takes all the extra time, before and after each file is transferred.  It's a small amount of time, but it adds up with thousands of files.  With one large file, there's just less overhead because the transmission is mostly just the data stream of the file's content with minimal packet transfer overhead for data integrity.

Comment: Why can't SAMBA send several files at a time? May be I can parallelize copying somehow? The question costs 100 times gain!

Comment: Also I don't understand general network overhead. In TCP/IP all data is transmitted in packets. 2Gb single file does NOT transmitted in one packet it split. This is definitely Samba problem.

Comment: The same is with harddrive. It stores data in sectors. If directory is in cache, then reading one big file should be the same as multiple of small.